# How to store variable and set the variable in field

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium 3.17.0.
I want to type a text from a javascript, but it doesn't work!

[I have tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CJ2D.png) (this types the text "undefined")

[and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FP2g.png) (this types the entire script as text)

but nothing works! maybe I'm doing wrong the javascript but I don't know, I'm new in all of this, please help!

btw this is my first post, sorry if I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to generate a random string using javascript and then store the value in a variable. Then enter that variable value using `type`.

you have to use `execute script` command to run the javascript and target (your javascript) should be `return "free text" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100)` as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]